# Slight differences in pixel values between OpenCV and Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to port some old matlab code to python. I chose OpenCV as I am familiar with the library. Despite that, I found results differ a bit (this program seems very sensible to small changes in texture), and I found pixel values are sightly different even with just reading the image from disk (I thought It could be some antialiasing or odd behavior when reecaling, but its there even before modifying anything)

I am aware of the different color order (RGB in matlab by default, BGR on OpenCV), but still pixel values are sometimes off by +-2 units (on 8-bit per color images). See for example in the following screencap, second pixel is 5-14-9 (RGB) when in matlab its 5-14-11. First pixel is exactly the same value.

[image: OpenCV/Matlab differences]

I can't think of any way to check the EXACT transformation/rounding that matlab is performing, or why this is different in the first place. Any Ideas on this matter?

Comment: We are talking about a jpg image, right? Its due to different compressions/decompression methods if that is the case, there is no fixed standard

Comment: How are you reading in the images? We can’t know what transformation is taking place if we don’t know exactly what you are doing. See [mre]. That said, the answer you have below is likely the issue.

Comment: As mentioned in David's answer, you're actually comparing MATLAB to "OCV in python", but you seem to ignore the difference between environments. You might want to consider the library [`mexopencv`](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/) which is a MATLAB interface to the C++ version of OCV. This would help you avoid any differences caused by transition from MATLAB to python, including row-vs-column major data structuring and indexing offeset-by-1.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you are looking at the correct pixel?
Matlab and Python differ in indexing, in Matlab the first index is 1, and in Python the first index is 0.

My guess is that you should be comparing the Matlab pixel [2,1] with the Python pixel value at index 0, which is 5-14-11 like the one in Matlab.

Comment: That is not the case, index 0 correspond to pixel [1,1] in matlab, not [2,1], and in that case it is equal on the three channels aswell. I think this is not an indexing problem, but a jpeg decompression one, as @Ander Biguri stated in a comment.